# IE asking open popup on download

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer

[image]

I am working on Angular 2 file download.

`HTML`

```
<a (click)="download(tempDisplayItem)" class="downloadNameColor">
  {{tempDisplayItem.displayFileName}}
</a>
```

`JS`

```
download (file) {
  window.open(file.url);
}
```

I am opening file in other tab on clicking on download. For `.xlsx` file it's showing a popup for open, save options. For `.txt`, it's not showing. I want to show popup for all files.How can I do that?

Comment: I guess xls files are opened with Excel(like) app?

Comment: Added screen shot. please refer.

Comment: In your Windows file manager what is the app linked to *.txt files ?